# Inlining CSS for HTML email templates

Tags: html, css, html-email, inline

Been trying to find a good inline tool and http://premailer.dialect.ca/ is the best I’ve found, but I believe it may not support  styling (not certain). It could also be an issue with the pseudo classes “first-child”, “nth-child”, etc.

It may also have something to do with the table style “table-layout” however I do not know how to get around this. I’ve tried all the values found on MDN, but my styles are still not showing up when converted.

Been working at this for a while with little progress. I could always go back and change my CSS to not use pseudo classes, but hoping there’s another option. Let me know if there are any better tools out there for converting to inline CSS.

Using SCSS and importing all scss files into a single all.scss file.

References:

[What tools to automatically inline CSS style to create email HTML code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791070/what-tools-to-automatically-inline-css-style-to-create-email-html-code)

[styling tr or td in emails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12025857/styling-tr-or-td-in-emails#)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: You can't inline a pseudo selector, since there is no element to add the style attribute to! In any case I would not personally consider pseudo selectors for an email since client support for them is very poor (Outlook doesn't support them, for example). I suggest you begin by researching what subset of CSS is supported by your target email clients https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: Ehm, @JonathanNicol you can inline style pseudo classes like first-child and nth-child perfectly fine.

Comment: Rob - noted.
Jonathan Nicol - that's what I figured and yes I was trying to use Outlook.
@Mr Lister - Not sure how you inline pseudo classes since they are selectors as opposed to attributes/values. If you could elaborate that would be helpful.

What I was hoping for is that the pseudo selectors would individually apply styles, but what seems to happen is either base styles are applied (ignoring my styles), or certain styles are ignored. I always try to override browser styles, even if I don't change their value.

I'm trying to build custom emails outside of paid tools like MailChimp.

Comment: @JoshBalsillie I meant you can give the styles to the appropriate elements. I.e. put the styles for `tr:first-child` only in the first tr. That is all. Of course you can't do the same with pseudo-elements such as `::marker` or `::selection`.

Comment: @Mr Lister - Makes sense. I was just thinking more in terms of coding my CSS in a way that would convert better to inline, as opposed to manually inlining my HTML. Perhaps a class or other selector would work better as well. Just thought I would check for quick fixes before considering more elaborate solutions, like building my own inline tool.

Comment: @Mr Lister You're right of course, I was thinking of pseudo elements. Blush.

Answer (score 0):

Closing off this question as it seems it is not the appropriate area to discuss email inlining tools.